# How to right-justify UILabel text?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How to right-justify UILabel text?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
```

[iOS Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW15) is a good resource.

Comment: UITextAlignmentRight is deprecated since iOS6. Use NSTextAlignmentRight instead.

Comment: `UITextAlignmentRight` or `NSTextAlignmentRight`  only right align the text but the text is not justified see @Hashem Aboonajmi or @Aryan answers

Answer (score 7):

You should set text alignment to justified and set attributed string base writing direction to RightToLeft:

```
var label: UILabel = ...
var text: NSMutableAttributedString = ...
var paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle().mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
paragraphStyle.baseWritingDirection = NSWritingDirection.RightToLeft
text.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length))
label.attributedText = text
```

Answer (score 6):

The new method call is:

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Answer (score 4):

you can using this Extension Below for Swift 5 :

```
extension UILabel {
   func setJustifiedRight(_ title : String?) {
      if let desc = title {
           let text: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: desc)
           let paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
           paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
           paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
           paragraphStyle.baseWritingDirection = NSWritingDirection.rightToLeft
           text.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length))
           self.attributedText = text
       }
    }
}
```

and simply set your text to your Label like This

```
self.YourLabel.setJustifiedRight("your texts")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is:
be careful if full justify needs to be applied, `firstLineIndent` should not be zero.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
paragraph.baseWritingDirection = NSWritingDirectionRightToLeft;
paragraph.firstLineHeadIndent = 1.0;
NSDictionary* attributes = @{
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.239 blue:0.451 alpha:1],NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph};
NSString* txt = @"your long text";
NSAttributedString* aString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: txt attributes: attributes];
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be through interface builder.
or **label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;**