# How to align Right-Justify UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, uilabel

*Remark:*

Implementing:

```
myLabel.textAlignment = .right
```

does *not* solves my problem, that is not what I am asking for.

---

What I am trying to achieve is to let the alignment for the label to be *Right-Justify*.

**To make it more clear:**

That's how `left` alignment looks:

[image]

And that's how `justify` alignment looks:

[image]

<sub>if you are not seeing any difference between the tow screenshots, you could recognize it by the right (trailing) constraint of the label, you will notice in the second screenshot the whole width of the label has been filled by the text.</sub>

As shown in the second screenshot, letting the label to be justified will make it *Left-Justify* by default, i.e the last line alignment is `left`.

How can I make let the label to be justified to the right? In other words, I want the text to be just like the 2nd screenshot except that I want the last short line to be shifted to the right.

<sub>If you wondering what is the purpose of doing such a thing, it would be appropriate for *right to left* languages.</sub>

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31283642/6788419

Comment: @user6788419 it worked! thanks alot.

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/HappyIosDeveloper/PersianJustify

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to [@user6788419](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6788419/user6788419) for mentioning the [appropriate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31283642/5501940).

For achieving it, you should work with [NSMutableParagraphStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle):

> An object that enables changing the values of the subattributes in a
>   paragraph style attribute.

It gives you the ability to the `alignment` and `baseWritingDirection` simultaneously, which leads to the desired output:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblDescription: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let text: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "In vertebrates, it is composed of blood cells suspended in blood plasma. Plasma, which constitutes 55% of blood fluid, is mostly water (92% by volume), and contains dissipated proteins...")

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .justified
        paragraphStyle.baseWritingDirection = .rightToLeft
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

        text.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length))

        lblDescription.attributedText = text
    }
}
```

The output would be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is not `ENUM` available for `right justified`!

You have to choose from `NSTextAlignmentLeft,NSTextAlignmentRight,NSTextAlignmentCenter,NSTextAlignmentJustified,NSTextAlignmentNatural`.

You have added screenshot of xcode's interface builder! once check it in simulator or device.

If you want space at left or right side in label with justified text then you can play with `edge insets`.

For example [Left padding in label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437579/ios-add-left-padding-to-uilabel).